# Lua: How to assigned a return value from a function to a local value of a different function in lua

Tags: lua

I am writing an extreme simple lua script about counting how many time an led flash

However, it keep giving me error when i try to assign a return value from previous function to a local variable in a different function.

```
function ReadADC1()
    local adc_voltage_value = 0
    adc_voltage_value = tonumber(adc.readadc()) * 2 -- 0.10 --get dec number out of this -- need to know where package adc come from
    --convert to voltage
    adc_voltage_value = adc_voltage_value *0.000537109375 --get V
    adc_voltage_value = math.floor(adc_voltage_value *1000 +0.5) --since number is base off resolution

    --print (adc_voltage_value)
    return adc_voltage_value

end
-- end of readADC1() TESTED

function counter()

    local ledValue = readADC1()
    --local interval -- interval between led on and off. If interval larger than 1 second, reset counter 

    --TODO add interval definition

    local interval = os.clock()
    while (true) do
        if ((ledValue >= OnThreshHold) and (interval < 1000)) then -- if value exceed threshhold, mean it on 
                ledCounter = ledCounter + 1
        elseif ((ledValue < OnThreshHold) and (os.clock() - interval > 1000)) then -- if led off for longer than 1 second
                ledCounter = 0  -- reset counter to one and prepare for next flashing
        else
            ledCounter = ledCounter -- not sure if we need this. Doing this might cause bug later on
        end
    end
    --return ledCounter
    print (ledCounter,"\r\n")
    end
-- end of counter()
```

As you can see, i am trying to assigned ledValue with adc_voltage_value from ReadADC1 function. I thought it suppose to work but turn out it didnt. It give me this error:

```
> +LUA ERROR: LEDcounter.lua:29: attempt to call global 'readADC1' (a nil value)
> 
> stack traceback:
> 
>     LEDcounter.lua:29: in main chunk
> 
>     [C]: ?
```

I have use blackbox debugging and test each function independently and ReadADC1 give me a nice number value. but when i test the counter() function, it gave me that error

Any suggestion or fix are welcome. I am trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking closely at your error, it's clear to see that Lua is having trouble finding a function (or indeed any other variable) by that name. If you look a bit closely, you can see that the call to `readADC1` is invalid because there is no such function. This is because the function you defined is called `ReadADC1` instead. Notice the capital letter and remember that variables are case-sensitive in Lua.

Comment: OMG. how can i miss that. Thank you. I have been working on that for a good amount of time